# Maximum values of implicit functions in specific range

Tags: mathematical-optimization

A simple implicit function

```
f = -0.000462963 x^2 - 0.1/Sqrt[0.0625 + (-3. + x)^2 + z^2]
    - 0.1/Sqrt[0.0625 + (3. + x)^2 + z^2];
E0 = -0.0575;
```

and the corresponding contour plot

```
C0 = ContourPlot[f == E0, {x, -12, 12}, {z, -12, 12}, 
     ContourStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.004]}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     ContourShading -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

[image]

My target is to numerically obtain the maximum value of $z$ in the interval $-6 < x < 6$.

However when I use

```
max = NMaximize[{x, f == E0}, {{x, -6, 6}, z}];
```

the program compute a maximum value outside the desired interval. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is Vxz in you Contourplot?

Comment: @JulienKluge It's an error. See my edit.

Comment: I think you mean `E0 = - 0.0575` as well.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer You are right!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was not nessecary to do it numerically. `Solve` with assumptions works.

Lets assume $x$ and $z$ to be $x,z\in\mathbb{R}$ and solving this:

```
sol = z /. Solve[f == E0, z, Reals];
```

This gives two solutions with a condition that $-11.1445 < x < 11.1445$.
So we refine:

```
sol=Refine[sol,{11>x>-11}];
```

Lets differentiate it and take only the first or second function. (The second funtion is the one you want but both are symmetrical so it does not matter.)

```
dsol=D[sol[[2]],x]
```

[image: differentiate function]

Now we can search for solutions:

```
xsol=x/.Solve[dsol==0,x,Reals]
```

> {{x->-11.1445},{x->-7.17004},{x->-3.16044},{x->0},{x->3.16044},{x->7.17004},{x->11.1445}}

So we see that $x\approx\pm 3.16044$ is your solution.

To get all pairs of solutions $(x,z)$ we map accordingly

```
solutionpoints=({#,sol[[2]]/.x->#})&/@xsol
```

> {{-11.1445,316.044},{-7.17004,0.305369},{-3.16044,2.61846},{0,0.
>   +3.0104 I},{3.16044,2.61846},{7.17004,0.305369},{11.1445,316.044}}

which gives you your two solutions to be: 
$$(x_{1,2},z_{1,2})=(\pm3.16044,2.61846)$$
and displaying the result:

```
Show[Plot[sol,{x,-10,10}],ListPlot[solutionpoints]]
```

[image: solutionpoints]

EDIT:
NMaximize would have also worked:

```
NMaximize[{z,f==E0,0<x<5},{x,z}]
```

> {2.61846,{x->3.16044,z->2.61846}}

Which is the same solution.